# Garbage Collection in Apache Storm

Tags: garbage-collection, apache-storm

Which is the default garbage collector in Storm and why?

Can someone please explain what happens to tuples in memory after they are acknowledged by a Bolt?

Answer (score 0):

Since Apache Storm is a JVM based project, then when it comes to garbage collection, the garbage collection policy used by Storm JVM process will be used.

I might be wrong but it looks to me that you are mixing two things here, JVM GC and Storm Acknowledge process.

Here is how acknowledge in Apache Storm was created:

Apache Storm spouts keep the messages (events) in their output queues until they are being acknowledged. The acknowledgement occurs only after the successful processing of a message (event) by the topology. If an acknowledgement comes for a message (event) within a reasonable amount of time, then the spouts clear the message from their output queue. If an acknowledgement didn’t come within a predefined period (30 second default), then the spouts replay the message again through the topology.

Should be read: [Guaranteeing Message Processing](https://storm.incubator.apache.org/documentation/Guaranteeing-message-processing.html).

Comment: Excuse me, I m a little bit confused with your response.
I think storm doesn't store full messages in memory. Basically, a spout implementation is responsible for re-emitting when an tuple failed to be completed. So storm doesn't need to keep tuple values. It only keeps the message id and data used to identified the spout task, isn't it ?

Comment: Hey thanks for clearing this up. But your response raised more questions in my mind.
Let me give you some background about my work - 
I am running a storm cluster and monitoring jvm metrics of every worker. I noticed that every time the garbage collector count reaches a particular value, it takes up so much CPU time that the worker is not able to send heartbeat. Thus, nimbus thinks that the worker is dead and rebalances the topology. When I changed the GC to ParNewGC from the default CMS that is used in storm, this problem went away. Is this related to GC in storm?How can I fix it?